# Unix:Recursively unzipping .zip file in respective folder

Tags: bash, shell, unix, unzip

I have a number of zipped files say `a.zip b.zip` etc in a folder. I would like to unzip those and put into a respective directory like `a,b`.Can you suggest me some unix script for it.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should not be much hard (untested!):

```
#!/bin/bash

for zip in *.zip ; do
    dir=${zip%.zip}
    mkdir "$dir"
    unzip -rd "$dir" "$zip"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use unzip utility in unix, as follows:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    for f in *.zip
    do
        echo "unzipping $f"
        unzip $f -d ${f%.*}
    done
```

Running this script in directory will unzip all the zip files in it as you wanted, say a.zip, b.zip will be unzipped to directories a and b respectively.

Answer (score 1):

[This previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107886/create-folder-for-zip-file-and-extract-to-it) has helped me to achieve this same function; I even created a script to help me remember on my computer:

```
$ ls *.zip|awk -F'.zip' '{print "unzip "$0" -d "$1}'|sh
```

---

Similarly, you can create an `alias` to execute a `bash` function:

```
$ alias munzip='for f in *.zip; do unzip -d "${f%*.zip}" "$f"; done'
```

and for a dry-run, to test it beforehand:

```
$ alias testmunzip='for f in *.zip; do echo unzip -d "${f%*.zip}" "$f"; done'
```

Just thought it might help to keep this related info on one page, in case someone else is looking for the same effects.