# Alias in bash not working

Tags: linux, bash

```
alias bp="cat $@ > $@.BACK"
```

My second idea was:

```
alias bp="cp $@{,.BACK}"
```

So i want to have a command to backup a file.
It does not raise any error but it simply doesn't work.

Comment: It would expand at the time you define the alias. Single-quotes might help, but I'm not sure you can express what you want using aliases without a function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make bash alias that takes parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter)

Answer (score 12):

Aliases are purely a textual replacement. If you want to use or manipulate the arguments, you need to create a function:

```
bp () {
  for file; do 
      cp -i "$file" "$file".BACK
  done
}
```