# Run php file in different browser using terminal other than default browser

Tags: macos, terminal

Hey guys is there a way to run php file in chrome or in any other browser using terminal.If I run my php file it automatically runs on my default browser but I just want to run on different browser using terminal(Mac OS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "open" command and specify a different browser with the "-a application" flag.

```
open -a /path/to/Chrome/binary yourfile.php
```

Manpage for "open" is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html).

Of course, you can also make an alias for that to save typing:

```
alias chrome="open -a /path/to/Chrome/binary yourfile.php"
```

then you can just type

```
chrome
```

If you have spaces in the path to your Chrome binary, you will need to escape them when defining the alias, something like this:

```
alias chrome="open -a \"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/contents/MacOS/Google Chrome\" yourfile.php"
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve hostc filename using `alias hostc="open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ http://localhost:8888/Sandbox/$1"` but it says file not found.how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Oh, I see. The problem is that your "path to app" is incomplete, you need to add "/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" onto the end. The actual binary is buried deeper inside the Chrome.app. I have amended again.

Comment: I think you need a filename at the end, not an "http:" path.

Comment: If u don't give that $1 then it opens the list of files under Sandbox directory and I can run any php or html file by clicking it.For php we need local server to be running so am http alongside and the parameter to that link so that I can open each file at a time.

Comment: Also you are trying to add a parameter to the alias with $1 which isn't directly possible, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter

Comment: Actually am using zsh I will have a look .