# Bash command aliasing for sshfs

Tags: bash, alias, mkdir, sshfs

I use `sshfs` to mount a remote drive onto my filesystem. However, whenever I unmount it, it removes the folder where it was created. My first question is what is the purpose of removing the folder. Second, is there a way to alias the `sshfs` command to execute `mkdir` in case when the directory given does not exist - so that I don't need to create one every time I want to mount a drive? I use bash as my default shell.

Comment: Aliases are very limited. You should be creating a function instead.

Comment: Thank you, I have just realized this myself. I will need to accept parameters to do what was suggested in the answer below. Here is a reference [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for the existence of a folder in bash with

```
[ -d "/path/to/the/folder" ]
```

and the negation would be

```
[ ! -d "/path/to/the/folder" ]
```

So an alias to test for / make the dir would look like:

```
alias test='if [ ! -d "/path/to/the/folder" ]; then mkdir -p "/path/to/the/folder"; fi'
```

Just work the above part into your `sshfs` alias.