# How to write parameterized Bash alias for Docker command

Tags: bash, shell, vim, docker, alias

I'm currently facing an issue.

I just pulled a Vim container to use it on a CoreOs system.
I try to create an alias to launch the Vim container instead of the one already present (principally because on this one I can install different plugins)

But for the moment it doesn't works and I don't know why.
The container has a Volume mount on `/home/dev`

My alias :

```
alias dockervim="docker run -ti --rm -v \"\$(pwd)\":/home/dev vimpadawan bash -c "vim \"\$1\"""
```

But when I write dockervim file_name it launches Vim but not with the file.

Someone has any ideas ?

Docker version

```
Client version: 1.6.2 
Client API version: 1.18 
Go version (client): go1.4.2 
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2-dirty 
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64 Server version: 1.6.2 Server 
API version: 1.18 
Go version (server): go1.4.2 
Git commit (server): 7c8fca2-dirty 
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

Thank you !

**EDIT 1 :**

With this command and a start.sh script, I can do what I want :

```
docker run --rm -ti -v $(pwd):/root/src -e FILENAME=Dockerfile vimpada
```

but when I try to make an alias of it, it shows this error :

> exec: "Dockerfile": executable file not found in $PATH FATA[0000]
>   Error response from daemon: Cannot start container
>   f579e5cd5bc61ee5da3b5cbeaf2a645c6183914739464cc4bf605202417467d9: 
> [8]
>   System error: exec: "Dockerfile": executable file not found in $PATH

**EDIT 2 :**

Just saw your answer helmbert, but it actually shows the same error as mine for your first function:

> [8] System error: exec: ".bashrc": executable file not found in $PATH

But **your second one works PERFECTLY !**
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: your alias is not correct, it complains about $1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bash aliases do not take arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter). You can try declaring a bash function, though:

```
function dockervim() {
    docker run -ti --rm -v "${PWD}":/home/dev vimpadawan vim "${1}"
}
```

Then simply call with `dockervim <filename>`.

Note that this solution only works with files in the current working directory. You should be able make it bomb-proof using the following function:

```
function dockervim() {
    filename=$(readlink -f $1)
    docker run -ti --rm -v "${filename}":/tmp/file-to-edit vimpadawan vim /tmp/file-to-edit
}
```