# Create a custom alias to open file adding extension

Tags: bash, ubuntu, alias

I'm using ubuntu, and want to create a custom alias in my .bashrc file, which execute

```
$xdg-open my_file_name.pdf
```

when I type

```
$pdf my_file_name
```

I'm sure there's an easy way to do that.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Someone has asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an alias; create a function, because you can't pass arguments to an alias.

```
pdf () {
    xdg-open "$1".pdf
}
```

Comment: Working well, thank you