# setting up variables in alias is not working

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I want my alias to pick up variables that I pass in commandLine:

For example, `startdocker 004` should execute the following

```
docker run -d -t -p 8080:8080 -v /var/source:/source -P mydockerregistry:5000/foo/bar:004
```

(004 is the tag I am passing in commandLine).

I tried the following in my .bashrc (sourced after the change).

```
alias startdocker='function dockerStartTag(){ echo "docker run -d -t -p 8080:8080 -v /var/source:/source -P mydockerregistry:5000/foo/bar: $1";};dockerStartTag'
```

when I run `startdocker 004`, It is not picking up 004.
It is empty and hence defaults to "latest" by docker.

what is the correct way to do it? what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I don't want to echo but execute the command.

The correct answer is provided below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make bash alias that takes parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to put a function inside an alias. Just do

```
function startdocker(){ echo "docker run -d -t -p 8080:8080 -v /var/source:/source -P mydockerregistry:5000/foo/bar: $1"; }
```

This now works on my system:

```
$ startdocker 004
docker run -d -t -p 8080:8080 -v /var/source:/source -P mydockerregistry:5000/foo/bar: 004
```

And to actually run it, we just need:

```
function startdocker(){ docker run -d -t -p 8080:8080 -v /var/source:/source -P mydockerregistry:5000/foo/bar: $1; }
```

Comment: oh may be I did not express correctly. I want that command to be executed. not printed on console

Comment: I tried that. it does not work. I get No such file or directory.

Comment: I also tried replacing idouble quotes with uptick `, so it can be executed. but it does not

Comment: @brainstorm Don't put double quote or backticks or anything else in the function. It should be `function startdocker(){ docker run -d ... $1; }`