# set docker container env from daemon configuration file

Tags: docker

**Question**: Is it possible to set docker container env from docker daemon configuration file?

When run a container, we can use `-e` flag to set specific environment variables inside container, such as `docker run -e foo=bar`.

But is it possible to configure docker daemon file such as `/etc/default/docker` or `/etc/sysconfig/docker`, then every docker container can has same env `foo=bar` instead of use `-e` flag.

```
[root@i-7guzl6d7 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/docker
# Docker Upstart and SysVinit configuration file

# Customize location of Docker binary (especially for development testing).
#DOCKER="/usr/local/bin/docker"

# Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
#DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"

# If you need Docker to use an HTTP proxy, it can also be specified here.
#export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"

# This is also a handy place to tweak where Docker's temporary files go.
#export TMPDIR="/mnt/bigdrive/docker-tmp"

# Set container environment here?
# export FOO=BAR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's currently no such option, however, there are some options to achieve this.

#### Using a Bash function

You can create a simple [bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter) that automatically sets these environment variables.

For example; this Bash function will automatically set `foo=bar` and `bar=baz` environment variables on `docker run`. Other docker commands are passed through as-is.

```
function docker() { case $* in run* ) shift 1; command docker run -e foo=bar -e bar=baz "$@" ;; * ) command docker "$@" ;; esac }
```

You can run the above line in your shell to load the function, or add it to your `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile` to have it loaded automatically when you open a new shell.

#### Using Docker Compose

There has been a proposal to implement a configuration file for default options (see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7232), but this was closed in favor of using [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

Have a look at docker compose to see if that fits your use-case. Docker Compose allows you to create a YAML file that defines your "project" -- all the containers that should be started to run your project, and how they should be configured. Compose supports variable substitution in the docker-compose.yml file, which allows you to set environment variables in your shell that are used inside the docker-compose.yml; see the documentation for that feature here; https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution

Comment: Thanks! I am running a mesos docker cluster, so maybe both are not my solution, but i can try the first one.

Comment: You're welcome! The function is a quick write-up (I'm far from a bash-guru), but you get the idea.