# "Aliasing" of Commands with Arguments

Tags: bash, alias

I know that some commands can be aliased through the shell, such as

```
alias mv="cp"
```

But I want to do something similar but with arguments (and yes, I have seen the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter), but my question is slightly different). Something similar to:

```
sshkill() {
  service sshd restart 
}
alias sshkill="killall sshd"
```

But this obviously doesn't work.

I wish to prevent users from directly killing the sshd (at least by accident) and make it restart (this is for a server where this has happened more than once). So, rather than *aliasing*, is there a way to *prevent* the command `killall sshd` from being executed and rather executing `service sshd restart` instead?

Comment: As an aside, a proper process supervision system (runit, daemontools, supervisord, upstart, systemd, launchd, etc etc) could be set to auto-restart sshd whenever it dies from any cause, either `killall` or otherwise -- and as such tools can use `waitpid()`, they can do so much more efficiently than polling-based solutions. I'd suggest using one. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Anything for efficiency. \o/ I'll make sure to look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to intercept `killall`, so:

```
killall() {
  if [ "$1" = "sshd" ]; then
    echo "some warning message, and perhaps service sshd restart"
  else
    command killall "$@"
  fi
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest `command killall "$@"`, not `/path/to/real/killall "$@"`; that way you still get the regular PATH lookup, making the function that much more portable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: amended. I'm glad I've learned something. Thx.

Comment: (Also see the second solution I offer in the answer to the linked question, which lets someone define a function for each subcommand they want to override -- for instance, `killall_sshd`; that way the definition of the wrapper for `killall` can be decoupled from the specific subcommands that are overridden).

Comment: What I learned today: you must put this in the _root_ .bashrc, because sudo is mean. :I