# Is it possible to use custom alias for mathematica run?

Tags: linux, alias

This is a general question on the use of alias command in linux, but I will take with a mathematica example to be more clear.
I want to creat an alias for mathematica run.
The mathematica run command for a mathematica file myfile1.m is

```
math -run "<<myfile1.m"
```

Now if I put this whole command as an alias in bashrc like

```
alias m='math -run "<<myfile1.m"'
```

it will run the file when I just type m in terminal.
But I want to know whether there is a way to use in the following way so that it could be used for any mathematica file run in a more sophisticated way :

```
alias m='math -run "<<file.m? "'
```

so that from the terminal I can run different mathematica files just typing

```
m myfile1.m
```

it will run

```
math -run "<<myfile1.m"
```

similarly for anyfile.m one just types

```
m anyfile.m
```

and it will run

```
math -run "<<anyfile.m"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to do something like:

```
alias m='math -run'
```

so the command would look like

```
m "<<anyfile.m"
```

which is look better, as for me. If you'd like to get deeper, look into this: 
[Link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-pass-argument-to-alias-command/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. But is it possible to use alias to do this?

Comment: I think it is not, according to some articles and this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter

Sorry, I can't try the functioning, I don't have linux close to me right now, but you can try @Goutam Das solution, maybe it will help.

If you are interested in that, give me your contacts, and I will send you some bash books I have, really good ones.

Comment: so nice of you!  Its really fun to dig these things! I will appreciate your help. You can send me at gkdgoutam@gmail.com

Comment: Shared a google drive directory with bash books to email specified, please check email :)
You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

With @Bandydan's suggestion the following seems to work.

```
function m() { math -run  "<<$@" ;}
```