# Linux: Create an alias to list particular process sorted by processname

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to create an `alias` which will list all process sorted by process name.

So if I write `myps processname`, it should return all the process names sorted by process names, excluding the grep command result itself.

Both of these are working fine

```
alias myps='ps aux|grep $1'
```

or just

```
alias myps='ps aux|grep '
```

But I am not able to use it like below

```
alias myps='ps aux|grep $1|grep -v grep|sort -k12'
```

I understand that while creating alias, passed variable is added at the last of the command.
Limitation is that I cannot change `.env` or `.profile` file and I cannot create new shell scripts on my unix box.

Can someone suggest any way to achieve it by alias or something?

Comment: You need to create a [function](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html), not an alias.

Comment: You might also want to read ["Make bash alias that takes parameter?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alias just expands to the string it represents, it doesn't really take any arguments. A function, on the other hand, seems to be exactly what you're looking for:

```
mureinik@computer /tmp $ myps() { ps aux|grep $1|grep -v grep|sort -k12; }
mureinik@computer /tmp $ myps bash
mureinik 10020  0.0  0.0 122552  6344 pts/2    Ss+  Mar13   0:00 bash
mureinik 11987  0.0  0.0 124068  6588 pts/3    Ss   09:17   0:00 bash
mureinik  6541  0.0  0.0 122716  6660 pts/0    Ss+  Mar13   0:01 bash
mureinik  7609  0.0  0.0 122592  6420 pts/1    Ss+  Mar13   0:00 bash
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this

Comment: The `grep -v grep` can be avoided with something like `grep "[${1:0:1}]${1:1}"` which also fixes the [quoting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable) error.  The substring facility is a Bash extension, though.