# Parameters alias for git

Tags: git, bash, terminal, alias

I work a little bit with alias on mac environment, and it was very useful. But i want to make some more boosting in my work using aliases. Now i want to make the add files, commit, and push to be done with aliases. So, i create an alias but it did not work; 
 Here is the code

```
alias track="trackFunction() { git add .;  git commit %@; git push}"
```

The output be like that:

> error: pathspec '%@' did not match any file(s) known to git.

So, i hope you guide me in this, because i'm new in all these stuff of work.

Answer (score 2):

When you call the alias, you want the content of `trackFunction` to be executed. But what you have defined is "when I call track, define function `trackFunction`".

Since you want your alias to accept parameters, you can use this (see this [answer about parameters for alias](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7131670/2032064)):

```
trackFunction() { git add .;  git commit "$@"; git push; }
alias track=trackFunction
```

But since you can already name your function `track`, you don't really need an alias, you can just put the function definition into your `.bashrc` or `.profile` file.

As a side note, I don't know what your intended workflow is, but you may want to include `git pull` before your `git push` to avoid rejections.

Comment: git add or git commit may fail, so I'd make all that conditional: `func() { git add . && git commit "$@" && git push; }`

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have a typo in the `git commit %@`. It should be a `$@` instead of the `%@` so you can pass parameters like `-m 'Commit message'`.

I also think writing a function is not necessary here. I have just successfully tested `alias track="git add .; git commit"` on a linux machine by calling `track -m 'Commit message'`.

Comment: Aliases don't use placeholders for parameters, so by chance your alias worked. Your alias expands to `git add .; git commit $@ -m 'message'`. Apparently your current shell has an empty set of parameters. You just want `alias track="git add .; git commit"`

Comment: @glennjackman I did try what you and dendress said, but did not work.

Comment: "did not work" is the worst possible description of a problem. What actually happened, and how does that differ from what you expected to happen. Edit your question and show us evidence (cut and paste from your terminal)