# Creating an alias and appending variable with text not working with git checkout

Tags: git, bash, git-checkout

I've created an alias in my *.bash_profile*

```
alias gco="git checkout origin/${1}"
```

but whenever I try to call a command like this:

```
gco master
```

it responds with:

```
error: pathspec 'origin/' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Could anyone help me understand why its returning these errors and not just concatenating the text properly? Thanks!

Comment: Aliases can't take arguments.  See this post: [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter)

Comment: The issue is that $@ can be used, but it will create a single space. So it would print `origin/ master`. It would work if you just want "git checkout master", that would be `alias gco="git checkout $@"`. But if you want it with the /, you'll need to make a function. The link @codeforester gave should help you.

Comment: I don't understand why everyone is saying alias's can't take arguments as the error clearly shows the argument taken in (although I'm a bash noob and am mostly likely wrong about the terminology). Anyways, @rowan thanks for the explanation, that makes sense. If you wrote that as an answer I would accept it :)

Comment: You're welcome @ForgetfulFellow, want me to write you the function as an example?

Comment: I'm good, I think i wrote something that works. Thanks though!