# Omit "Is a directory" results while using find command in Unix

Tags: unix, grep, directory, find

I use the following command to find a string recursively within a directory structure.

```
find . -exec grep -l samplestring {} \;
```

But when I run the command within a large directory structure, there will be a long list of

```
grep: ./xxxx/xxxxx_yy/eee: Is a directory
grep: ./xxxx/xxxxx_yy/eee/local: Is a directory
grep: ./xxxx/xxxxx_yy/eee/lib: Is a directory
```

I want to omit those above results. And just get the file name with the string displayed. can someone help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whenever you are saying `find .`, the utility is going to return all the elements within your current directory structure: files, directories, links...

If you just want to find files, just say so!

```bash
find . -type f -exec grep -l samplestring {} \;
#      ^^^^^^^
```

However, you may want to find all files containing a string saying:

```
grep -lR "samplestring"
```

Comment: `find -type f` and `grep -r` or `grep -R` are good choices... just to complete the answer, perhaps add that `-d skip` specifically takes care of `Is a directory` issue... it is useful at least in cases like using shell options for recursive search, for ex: `grep -d skip -l 'samplestring' **/@(*.txt|*.log)`

Comment: @Sundeep nice! I wasn't aware of the `-d` flag.

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter  to create a function in your `.bashrc` to do this, so you only need to supply `samplestring`

Answer (score 20):

`grep -s` or `grep --no-messages`

It is worth reading the portability notes in [the GNU grep documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Command_002dline-Options) if you are hoping to use this code multiple places, though:

`-s
--no-messages
 Suppress error messages about nonexistent or unreadable files. Portability note: unlike GNU grep, 7th Edition Unix grep did not conform to POSIX, because it lacked -q and its -s option behaved like GNU grep’s -q option.1 USG-style grep also lacked -q but its -s option behaved like GNU grep’s. Portable shell scripts should avoid both -q and -s and should redirect standard and error output to /dev/null instead. (-s is specified by POSIX.)`

Comment: I don't think it is useful to hide errors, when you can avoid them. See my answer

Comment: Finally!  The correct answer to this question!  When you are interested in only seeing the grep 'hits' and not all the un-useful trash like 'Is a directory' this is the way to do it.  I've been trying to use -v to suppress anything with 'directory' in it - but it's obvious now why that won't work: these 'Is a directory' are messages not the grep results themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude directory warnings in grep with the `--exclude-dir` option:

```
grep --exclude-dir=* 'search-term' *
```

Just look at the `grep --help` page:

> --exclude-dir=PATTERN directories that match PATTERN will be skipped.