# How to create shell alias with args?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh

I use the command really often:

```
ack searchexpre -l --print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e sedexpression
```

I would like to create an alias like:

```
searchandreplace searchexpre  sedexpression
```

How I can do that?

Comment: BTW -- please tag bash *or* zsh *or* sh, but not two or three of those at once. They're different shells, not mutually compatible with each other (except inasmuch as bash is *almost* a superset of POSIX sh but for its noncompliant `echo` implementation), and while in this particular case there's a single answer that works for all of them, (1) that's not always true, and (2) the excess tagging means that someone needs to test each answer in multiple shells to evaluate that answer's correctness.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter)

Comment: you should also consider using ag instead of ack it's about 10x faster in my testing;
https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule of thumb with aliases is that if you have to ask, you should be using a function instead:

```
searchandreplace() {
    ack "$1" -l --print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e "$2"
}
```

You can now call `searchandreplace searchexpre  sedexpression`

Comment: is there any way to give name to the parameter? like doint searchandreplace(arg1,arg2) { .... } ?

Comment: No, `sh` and `bash` do not support named parameters. You can assign `$1` and `$2` to variables with whichever names you want though