# Git rebase ZSH shell alias

Tags: bash, git, alias, zsh, rebase

I picked up a [git alias online](https://hugogiraudel.com/2018/02/17/how-i-use-git/#rewriting-history) that is supposed to be the command `git rebase -i HEAD~$1` where `$1` is a number passed to the alias. Here is the git alias I've got setup in my `.zshrc` file:

```
alias grn="! sh -c \"git rebase -i HEAD~$1\" -"
```

Example usage from the terminal:

```
$ grn 3 // This should translate to git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

The issue i'm running into is that the passed integer argument (e.g. `3`), is not being passed to my alias so the git alias is effectively always running `git rebase -i HEAD~`.

Any clues on how to fix this alias?

Comment: After checking your alias in [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) it said that I am missing space after exclamation mark. Could you try with `alias grn="! sh -c \"git rebase -i HEAD~$1\" -"` then?

Comment: Nice, so the command runs now, but it doesn't take in a passed integer argument. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Refering to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7131670/7411306) I would say having an alias which takes parameters is not possible. You could easily do it with single-line function though. Just put `grn() { git rebase -i HEAD~"$1"; }` in `.zshrc` and you can run it the same way as an alias.

Comment: Oh, that's beautiful! Thanks @dmadic. If you write that up as an answer I'll mark it as accepted ✅

Comment: I copied it to an answer. Thanks @RobertCooper. :)

Comment: The alias from the linked article is a git alias, not a shell alias.

Comment: @rkta Oh wow, you're right! If I add the command to my `.gitconfig` as an alias, it works as intended. Thanks for pointing that out :). I wasn't even aware that git aliases were a thing to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refering to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7131670/7411306) I would say having an `alias` which takes parameters is not possible.

You could easily do it with single-line function though.

Just put:

```
grn() { git rebase -i HEAD~"$1"; }
```

in `.zshrc` and you can run it the same way as an alias.

Answer (score 4):

Shell alias with parameters is impossible, but [git alias](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-alias) is definitely possible. Either

```
git config alias.grn '! sh -c "git rebase -i HEAD~$1" -'
```

or

```
git config alias.grn '!f() { git rebase -i HEAD~$1; }; f'
```

Run as `git grn 3`.

Comment: so good! Thank you. I've added this alias into my .gitconfig file :) 


`rb = "!f() { git rebase -i HEAD~${1}; }; f"`