# Shortcut command for create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs

I'm lazy and I despise typing 'create-react-app some-app' to use create react app. Is it possible to change the command to something like: 'cra some-app'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bash aliases for this. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-useful-bash-aliases-and-functions

Though I must say, how often are you doing this that it becomes a problem?

EDIT -

I forgot that you need the argument of the project name...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7131683/5602665

Check out this answer here for how to create a function. That's your best bet

Comment: Thanks! Honestly, its not that often... but still bugs me.