# shortcut for typing kubectl --all-namespaces everytime

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, kubectl

Is there any alias we can make for all-namespace as kubectl don't recognise the command `kubectl --all-namespaces` or any kind of shortcut to minimize the typing of the whole command.

Comment: Dont think there is a way to create alias that way. I use `alias ksa='kubectl get all --all-namespaces'` to make it shorter.

Comment: @Tinkal Gogoi, how about creating an alias in dot profile and giving it a try once?

Comment: If you decide to go this way, make sure that `get all` is really what you want kubectl to display (some resources are omitted that way, just a friendly reminder).

Comment: This answer is depreciated and not current anymore.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Is there any alias we can make for all-namespace

Based on [this excellent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42466441/9663586) you can create alias that inserts arguments between prefix and suffix like so:

```
alias kca='f(){ kubectl "$@" --all-namespaces -o wide;  unset -f f; }; f'
```

and then use it regularly like so:

```
kca get nodes
kca get pods
kca get svc,sts,deploy,pvc,pv
```

etc..

**Note**: There is `-o wide` added for fun as well to get more detailed info about resources not normally namespaced like `nodes` and `pv`...

Comment: Most of the other answers to that question recommended simply writing a shell function and that seems like it'd be more appropriate here.

Comment: Sure, in referenced SO answer it is discussed at length and I wholeheartedly suggest a read on that! This is simply an attempt to answer a question "is there any alias we can make"? Btw, this uses function as well, albeit a bit different :)

Answer (score 69):

New in kubectl v1.14, you can use `-A` instead of `--all-namespaces`, eg:

`kubectl get -A pod`

(rejoice)

Reference:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#a-note-on-all-namespaces

Comment: I vote to make THIS the accepted answer! Please change it! It has double as many upvotes.