# How to list Kubernetes in different namespaces by its kind?

Tags: json, linux, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, jsonpath

I've a task list to Kubernetes pods by its kind. For Eg List kubernetes pods that are in different namespace using Jsonpath.
I'm using the below command which is not working.

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.items.kind=="Elasticsearch")]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the following command.

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.kind=="Pod")]}' --all-namespaces
```

Comment: you can also use the Shorthand `-A`  insted of `--all-namespaces` [shortcut for typing kubectl --all-namespaces everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57542244/4018180)

Answer (score 0):

To see the pods in different namespace:

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.kind=="Pod")]}' -n <namespace-name>
```