# Using last to get last 8 logins of the user

Tags: unix

Create an alias named `mylogin` that lists the specified number of most recent logins made by the user. For example, if a user enters `mylogin 8`
in the command line, the system will list the eight latest logins from the user. The alias should work for any user without any modification.

I am able to do

```
last username | head -8
```

to get last 8 logins of `username`, where I replace my name with `username` but I can't figure how to make it work for any user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your command work with any user try

```
last $(whoami)| head -8
```

I replaced the parameter `username` in your command with `$(whoami)` which is the output of `whoami`. Command `whoami` prints the user name associated with the current effective user ID. When you run this without using `sudo` or other means for changing the effective user ID it should be the login name of the current user.

or

```
last -n 8 $(whoami)
```

If your `last` command supports option `-n 8` or simply `-8` you can specify the number of lines to be printed without piping through `head`. Note that this may add a line stating when the `wtmp` file has been started. With `| head -8` this additional line will get removed if there are enough login lines above it.

## alias or function

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/7131683/10622916
you cannot pass an argument to an alias. Arguments will be appended to the expansion of the alias.

So it's not possible to insert the argument into the alias expansion or combine it with `-` to build an option.

If you need an alias, not a function, you can use

```
alias mylogin='last $(whoami)|head -n'
```

Then you can call

```
mylogin 8
```

which will be expanded to

```
last $(whoami)| head -n 8
```

This solution has the drawback that you will get an error from `head` when you call

```
mylogin
```

without argument because this gets expanded to

```
last $(whoami)| head -n
```

To avoid this error you could use a function instead of an alias.

```
mylogin () {
    if [ -n "$1" ]
    then
        last -n "$1" $(whoami)
    else
        last $(whoami)
    fi
}
```

In the function you can also use

```
last $(whoami) | head -n "$1"
```

instead of

```
last -n "$1" $(whoami)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.