# Dynamic directory name for a bashrc alias

Tags: linux, bash, command

I have created an alias `gotochild2` in `.bashrc` file to change a particular path `/parent/child1/child2`. Now I want the user to enter his directory within `child2` which will be dynamic. 
For example, `gotodir files` has to go `/parent/child1/child2/files`. How this can be specified in `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an alias use a function if you want to pass a parameter like `gotodir files`.
See [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670)

```
gotodir () {
    cd "/parent/child1/child2/$1"
}
```