# Can I add a parameter in-between my command?

Tags: bash, alias

Coding is one of my weaker areas and this is my first question on Stack Overflow.

What I want to is add a parameter in-between my command, and I'm thinking it can be done with an alias or function.

The command I am using is telnet and it is used to log into our switches.

The full command:

```
$ telnet switchname.compname.com
```

What I want to type:

```
$ enter 'switchname'
```

In turn, making the telnet command a simple enter and not having to consistently type `.compname.com` every time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You require a function for this and not an alias. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670) post. It tells you how you can achieve this (although for another example).

Comment: Also take your time for the [tour].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Adding to what kvantour said already: A good first question, except for one thing: This site is not a programming service, i.e. people are expected to show and ask questions regarding their own effort to solve a problem.

Answer (score 1):

A simple function does nicely:

```
enter() { telnet $1.compname.com; }
```

Comment: Just to be clear, while this is a valid answer., it just gives a solution but it does not explain at all why a function should be used and how it works. Some references would be nice.

Comment: `enter() { local swname=${1:-defaultswitch}; telnet $swname.compname.com; }` aliased to `alias mytelnet=enter` may prove more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to open the `telnet` session to the switchname given by the first argument (or to your default switchname if no argument is provided), e.g. in `.bashrc` you could do:

```
mytelnet() {
    local swname=${1:-defaultname}  ## use local vars within function
    telnet $swname.compname.com     ## connect to your switch
}
```

Then create the `alias` you want for `enter`, e.g.

```
alias enter='mytelnet'
```

Now at the command line you can type:

```
$ enter                 ## to go to defaultname.compname.com
```

or

```
$ enter switchname      ## to go to switchname.compname.com
```

For testing you can just enter the function and alias on the command line, e.g.

```
$ mytelnet() { local swname=${1:-defaultname}; telnet $swname.compname.com; }
$ alias enter='mytelnet'
```

Then telnet away...

(**note:** you can simply name your function `enter()` and do away with the `alias`. I just find it convenient to define my functions at the top of my `.bashrc` and then create aliases, as needed, in the various sections below, but using an alias is by no means a requirement)

Comment: Why create an alias? Just name the function `enter`.

Comment: No dying need, I generally just like the flexibility of using an alias to the functions at the top of my .bashrc. You could just name the function `enter()`, Habit more than anything since I use one .bashrc between multiple distros and have conditional blocks where aliases are assigned based on the `NAME` in `/etc/os-release`.

Comment: This worked perfectly! thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help. Bash is an amazingly capable shell and there is a LOT to it. It's not something you learn in a day, a month, a year, ... So take your time and enjoy the learning process. There is no replacement for [`man bash`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) even if it is a little cryptic at first. It contains the whole story, it just takes a long while to digest.

Comment: Thanks a lot David, still very new at this so I will take your advice on taking it slow and even looking into man bash.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an `alias` in your `rc`file, like `~/.bashrc`, for example.

```
alias mytelnet='telnet the.desired.site'
```

Then `source` your `rc`file like

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or the equivalent

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

and type `mytelnet` to execute the command.

Or just use a `bash` variable, like

```
VAR="the.desired.site"
```

and execute `telnet` this way:

```
telnet $VAR
```

Also you can add a function to your `rc` file, like David C. Rankin mentioned.

```
function mytelnet () {
    telnet <<< "$@"
}
export -f mytelnet
```

`<<< "$@"` will feed telnet in the same way, as if you are using any other command on the commandline with their additional parameters, like in `bash` `$1`, `$2` and so on.
`export -f` marks the function *mytelnet* to be passed to child processes in your environment.

Comment: Perhaps have the alias be to a function that takes the switchname as an argument and then provide a `local` variable within the function set to the argument (or default switchname if none provided) could provide a bit more flexibility?

Comment: David, this have been a very good idea, please review my edit.

Comment: That's good improvement, though you ought to figure out how to make the `compname.com` a fixed part of the name so the user only has to provide the `switchname` part in order to connect. Also, since POSIX provides for the function taking arguments, you generally want to avoid bashisms (e.g. the *herestring* `<<<`) to provide the switchname when it can be done simply by passing as an argument (technically called a *positional parameter*). See if you can implement that with your solution.