# In Bash scripting, how to change directory to a file's directory path using the function `dirname`?

Tags: bash, alias, cd, dirname, positional-parameter

I would like to change directory to that of a file by defining an alias:

```
alias direc=`cd | echo dirname "$1"`
```

but this doesnt work. Any ideas are appreciated for how I can restructure this.

Comment: what is the use of this alias? It does exactly the same as dirname? Why not use 'dirname' directly?

Comment: Hi, I actually would like to change directory to the directory of a file. This way I envision doing `direc path/to/file` to automatically change to it. I updated the question, my apologies

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter) You cannot pass arguments to an alias, only to functions, but you can make an alias that calls a function if you so desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going backwards. The result of `dirname` should be the *argument* to `cd`, rather than `dirname` trying to use the output of `cd`.

Also, use a function instead of an alias.

```
direc () {
  cd "$(dirname "$1")"
}
```

Comment: I defined functions as `function direct{cd "$(dirname "$1")"}`. Is this equivalent to the above you have?

Comment: Yes, but it uses non-standard syntax which has no real reason for existing in new. Use the standard form of function definition that I have shown. (My understanding is that the `function` keyword is allowed mainly to ease the use of code written for `ksh`, though I'm not even sure if `ksh` made any distinction between the two forms.)

Comment: @user321627 You need to add blanks and a semicolon: `function direct { cd "$(dirname "$1")"; }` or, as mentioned, `direct() { cd "$(dirname "$1")"; }`

Comment: (or with parameter expansion: `direct() { cd "${1%/*}"; }`)