# git clone and cd into it

Tags: linux, bash, git

If I wanted to make a directory and change directory into it all in one line, I could do something like this:

`mkdir dir_name && cd $_`

How can I do the same with `git clone`?

The command, `git clone repo_url && cd $_`, won't work obviously, because there's no such directory as `repo_url`. But is it possible to do it in one line?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to find the name automatically, you could try something like this:

```
git clone https://host.com/you/the-repo.git && cd "$(basename "$_" .git)"
```

That way you don't have to specify a folder name to git.

### Explanation

#### [$_](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280453/understand-the-meaning-of)

The underscore is a special [bash variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) that holds the **last argument** to the previous command.

Example:
The following command will print 'C': `touch "A" "B" "C" && echo "$_"`

In the above git command, `$_` will be `https://host.com/you/the-repo.git`

#### [basename](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=b-basename-command)

Returns the base file name of a string parameter.

`basename string [suffix]`

The basename command reads the String parameter, deletes any prefix that ends with a / (slash) and any specified Suffix parameter, and writes the remaining base file name to standard output.

In the above git command, the basename command will return `the-repo` (which is what git will have named the repo it just cloned).

Comment: Consider simplifying it's usage further by adding it to a function in your `.bash_profile` arbitrarily named `gitclone` - in a similar way to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter#answer-7131683). For example: **1)** Run the following command to append the `gitclone` function to your `.bash_profile` file: `echo $'\n'"function gitclone() { git clone \"\$1\" && cd \"\$(basename \"\$_\" .git)\" || return; }" >> ~/.bash_profile`. **2)**  Create a new session and run the simplified command in the future: `gitclone "http://repo_url.git"`

Comment: @chepner Hi, can I ask the reason you edited this answer to put double quotes around `$(basename $_ .git)`?

Comment: I did that in the other answer; `$_` refers to the last argument of the previous command, and that answer made the desired directory name the last argument of the `git` command, so that the usage you asked about in your question would work. (The original would have worked fine as well, but just involved typing the directory name twice.)

Comment: @chepner Right, yes I got that, I made a mistake in my comment, fixed it. I meant the edit you did on this answer, when you put double quotes around `$(basename $_ .git)`.

Comment: That's just good practice, in case the full directory name contains any characters that would be subject to shell processing if left unquoted. (Actually, `$_` itself should be quoted as well; I'll fix that.)

Comment: If you're cloning from a repo url without `.git` at the end (like a github repo url for instance), remove the `.git` from the `basename` command

Answer (score 5):

You can add a directory name for the git clone command:

```
git clone repo_url my_repo_dirname && cd "$_"
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't really like aliases with special names like `cdls` or `gitclone` because on a new system I can't remember the original commands.
That's why I like the following solution for aliases:

```
## git extra features 
# - clone + cd 
function git() {
    if [ $1 = "clone" ]
    then 
        command git $@ && cd "$(basename "$_" .git)"
    else
        command git $@
    fi
}
```

Using `command` calls the original `git` command, not this one in the `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: I LOVE IT!! For noobs like me: add this like so: `nano ~/.zshrc` and paste, reload setting with `zsh`

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `~/.bashrc`. Don't forget to source it!

```
function gccd { git clone "$1" && cd "$(basename $1 .git)"; }
export -f gccd
```

gccd stands for git clone and cd. This is the function equivalent of an alias. Now you can type: `gccd <repo>`. It will do exactly what you want.

Updated so that it works with both URL and with trailing .git. Thanks @kost

Comment: This function doesn't work properly. It tries to `cd reponame.git` but should `cd reponame`

Comment: `function gccd { git clone "$1" && cd "$(basename $1 .git)"; }` -- this one works

Comment: I think i wrote this function a while back when it was more normal to clone a git repo with just the URL. Thanks I will update my function and answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
git clone http://repo_url.git && cd "!$:t:r"
```

**Imp:** Do not forget the double quotes in the `cd` command, else it won't work in some other shells or Git Bash in Windows.

How does it work?

The first command is the obvious `git clone` command. The second `cd` command is intriguing.

Now there is something called [Word Designators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html) for command history

- `!$` is the last part of the last command run

Here the last command run would be `git clone http://repo_url.git`. This command consists of three parts. 1. `git`, 2. `clone` and 3. `http://repo_url.git`. And `http://repo_url.git` is the last part. Hence `!$` ==> `http://repo_url.git`

Then there is something called [Word Modifiers](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Modifiers.html), which modify the string preceding it.

- `:t` removes all leading file name components, leaving the tail

So here `!$:t` would be read like `(!$):t`. Hence `!$:t` ==> `repo_url.git`

- `:r` removes the trailing suffix from filenames like `abcd.xyz`, leaving `abcd`

So here `!$:t:r` would be read like `{(!$):t}:r`. Hence `!$:t:r` ==> `repo_url`

So it would `cd` to `repo_url`

To debug this yourself, use `:p` which just prints the command preceding it without executing it. Equivalent would be `echo`

Run the following in the exact sequence

1. `git clone http://repo_url.git`
2. `!$:p` ==> `http://repo_url.git`  (or `echo !$`)
3. `!$:t:p` ==> `repo_url.git`       (or `echo !$:t`)
4. `!$:t:r:p` ==> `repo_url`         (or `echo !$:t:r`)

Comment: This looks promising, but does it really work? It uses history to read the last command, but when cloning, you do not have the command in history yet.

Comment: @brablc It will only work in interactive shells. So it won’t work in a Dockerfile, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Bash function:

```
m.git.clone(){
    local url="${1}" dir="${2}"
    if [[ "${dir}" == "" ]]; then 
        dir="$(basename "${url}" .git)"
    fi
    
    git clone "${url}" "${dir}" && cd "${dir}"
}
```

Can be used:

```
m.git.clone git@github.com:user/path.to.git
```

Or

```
m.git.clone git@github.com:user/path.to.git customDir
```

Both work and cd only on success.