# Make a bash function that takes some special chars in the parameters

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Starting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter), I want to archive anything using "`archive name_dest [folder+filter]`"

I've tried:

```
archive() { tar cjf "`(date '+%Y.%m.%d-%Hh%Mm%Ss')`-$1.tar.bz2" "$2"; }
```

When I do this special chars are not handled:

```
> archive dev "dev/*"
tar: dev/*: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

(of course the `dev` is a directory in my current path)
What is the proper way? I would really like to type *only* `archive dev dev/*`.

Comment: `archive dev dev` should achieve what you want. The error is because you quoted second argument, and `dev` directory does not contain a file name `*`.

Comment: If I dont quote the second argument I get another type of error. If you could try you would see what I mean

Comment: The second parameter has be a directory, not a list of files you'd get with `dev/*`. Run `archive dev dev` (or if you meant `/dev` then `archive dev /dev`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcards (like `*`) only expand into a list of matching filenames when they're *not* in quotes. One possibility would be to leave `$2` unquoted in the function:

```
archive() { tar cjf "`(date '+%Y.%m.%d-%Hh%Mm%Ss')`-$1.tar.bz2" $2; }
```

...but that can have some unpleasant consequences. Most obviously, if you're trying to archive a folder with spaces or some other shell metacharacters in the name, it'll get confused because *those* aren't in quotes either.

A much better solution is to pass the folder+pattern unquoted in the first place, so it expands before the function gets invoked. You run

```
archive dev dev/*
```

...and the shell expands it to something like

```
archive dev dev/file1 dev/file2 dev/file3
```

But then you have to write the function so it doesn't just archive `$2`, but all arguments starting at `$2`. This isn't too hard; just record `$1`, use `shift` to remove it from the arg list, then use `"$@"` to get all remaining arguments. And as long as we're using local variables, I'd put the destination filename in one as well (just for general neatness):

```
archive() {
    local name_dest="$1"
    local archive_name="$(date '+%Y.%m.%d-%Hh%Mm%Ss')-${name_dest}.tar.bz2"
    shift
    tar cjf "${archive_name}" "$@"
}
```