# Bashrc edit with values in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I know how to add aliases to bashrc and run it.

For example:

```
$ sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

and add line;

```
alias startmyservicescommand='/home/startmyservice.sh'
```

but, now i want to add "variables" to my command.

for example my command will be :

```
iptables -A INPUT -s IP-ADDRESS -j DROP
```

and i want use command as:

```
ip_ban IP-ADDRESS (ip_ban is my self alias and IP-ADDRESS is a variable)
```

How can i add this command to bashrc?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter)

Comment: Better to use a shell function.

Answer (score -1):

For ubuntu 14 this worked for me :

```
alias ipbanekle='_ipbanekle(){ iptables -A INPUT -s "$1" -j DROP; /etc/init.d/iptables-persistent save; /etc/init.d/iptables-persistent reload; }; _ipbanekle'
```

For 16 and higher;

```
alias ipbanekle='_ipbanekle(){ iptables -A INPUT -s "$1" -j DROP; netfilter-persistent save; netfilter-persistent reload; }; _ipbanekle'
```

And call:

```
ipbanekle ip.address
```

thats all. Thanks.

Comment: Also you need to install iptables-persistent package