# How to use alias command to create command with custom input?

Tags: linux, terminal

How can I alias a command that uses custom input in terminal?

For example, let's say a command

```
$ oj d https://codeforces.com/contest/1348/problem/A
```

In this command 1348 and 'A' can change.
How can I achieve this?

Something like I can alias the whole command as,

```
$ oj d 1348 A
```

such that it can act like same.

Comment: Duplicate: [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases do not accept parameters. You need to write a function or a separate script.

**Bash/Zsh function:**

Define the following function in your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc` depending on what interactive shell you use:

```sh
mycommand() {
    oj d https://codeforces.com/contest/"$1"/problem/"$2"
}
```

**Shell script:**

Create the file `mycommand` with the following content in your `$PATH` and make it executable:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
oj d https://codeforces.com/contest/"$1"/problem/"$2"
```

`$1` and `$2` are positional parameters. If you call the script or function like `$ mycommand 1348 A`, `$0` gets mapped to *mycommand*, `$1` to *1348*, `$2` to *A* and so on. We put the double quotes around the variables in case they contain whitespace to prevent word splitting.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using alias. To do that you have to create a custom function in `.basrch` or `.zshrc` and after that you can do any kind of stuff on that function.

For the thing that you want to do, you can create a function with any name you want and inside the function you can write the logic to execute your command. You can write the function like that:

```
command(){
    oj d https://codeforces.com/contest/$1/problem/$2
}
```

Now if you execute `oj d 1348 A` this command then it will replace the d with `$1` and it will replace the A with `$2`. You can write any command like that and you can do what ever thing you want to do.

**Disclaimer:** Don't forget to use `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc` command after changing the `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file. Otherwise the commands are not going to work.