# Shell alias input search syntax for a negated find search

Tags: find, negate

Mac OSX Bash Shell

I want to use find to identify anything (directories or files) which do not follow an input pattern.

This works fine:

```
find . -path /Users/Me/Library -prune -o \! \( -path '*.jpg' \)
```

However I want to have a general ability to do from a bash alias or function eg:

```
alias negate_find="find . -path /Users/Me/Library -prune -o \! \( -path ' "$1" ' \)"
```

To allow shell input of the search term (which may contain spaces).    The current syntax does not work, returning `unknown primary or operator` on invocation.    Grateful for assistance in what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why,  but separating the input parameter into its own string seemed to work.   Here it is as a working shell function and case invariant.

```
negate_find () {
search="$1"
lowersearch=$(echo "$search" | awk '{print tolower($0)}')
uppersearch=$(echo "$search" | awk '{print toupper($0)}')
echo "search = $search"
find . -path $HOME/Library -prune -o \! \(  -path "$lowersearch"  \)  -a \! \(  -path "$uppersearch"  \)
}
export -f negate_find
```

Comment: This worked because you used a function instead of an alias. Aliases cannot use `$1`. That you used `search=$1` and then `$search` instead of `$1` is irrelevant. Btw: Most `find` implementations have the case-insensitive `-ipath` (macOS' has too). You might want to use this instead of `lowersearch` and `uppersearch`.