# Running the alias in bash command doesn't work

Tags: bash

```
alias testing="date | tee /home/anupamkhatiwada/fulldate.txt | cut --delimiter=" " --field=1 | tee /home/anupamkhatiwada/shortdate.txt | xargs echo hello"
```

On typing test in terminal and pressing enter getting

> testing: command not found

Comment: Any non-trivial alias is usually better done as a function.

Comment: Actually I'm just starting out with linux and the shell so I don't know how to write and use functions yet.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you have embedded `"` in your string.  Try this instead:

```
alias testing='date | tee /home/anupamkhatiwada/fulldate.txt | cut --delimiter=" " --field=1 | tee /home/anupamkhatiwada/shortdate.txt | xargs echo hello'
```

Comment: Tried doing it. Still returning command not found. It's in a file .bash_aliases in home.

Answer (score 0):

When I run that command I get this error message:

```
-bash: alias: ` --field': invalid alias name
```

And as PaulProgrammer pointed, seems to be due to the delimiter character used in your `cut` command, the double quotes `"`, which conflicts with the ones used to define the alias. Hence, another workaround would be:

```
alias testing="date | tee /home/anupamkhatiwada/fulldate.txt | cut --delimiter=' ' --field=1 | tee /home/anupamkhatiwada/shortdate.txt | xargs echo hello"
```

Comment: Tried doing that as well along with PaulProgrammer's suggestion both are returning command not found. Its in a file called .bash_aliases in home.

Comment: Are you sourcing your `.bash_aliases` file after you make changes on it? Run `source ~/.bash_aliases` and try again.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you so much! I'm doing a udemy course. The instructor didn't mention anything about source.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function instead of an alias, then you don't have to worry about quoting conflicts.

```
testing() {
    date | tee /home/anupamkhatiwada/fulldate.txt | cut --delimiter=" " --field=1 | 
        tee /home/anupamkhatiwada/shortdate.txt | xargs echo hello
}
```

Functions have the added benefit that they can take parameters, which can be inserted in the middle of the commands. See [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter)

Comment: Thank you Barmar. I'm doing a udemy course on linux. Haven't reached functions yet but the solution provided by hads0m in comments in the answer below worked. I hadn't declared the source. Actually I didn't know about the source command.