# how rsync request 3 arguments when called from the console?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, rsync

How in the alias for the rsync command to request 3 arguments when called from the console?

I want the console to ask me when I call the alias:

1. server = example = root@0.0.0.0
2. dir1
3. dir2

```
alias get_files="rsync -chavzP --stats --exclude 'cache/*' --exclude 'tmp/*' server():dir1() dir2()"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter)

Comment: What does your question have to do with `python`?