# How can I add a default parameter to a `Bash` function?

Tags: bash, function, default-value, parameter-expansion

Most of the time when I am in some directory and running some job from the command line, I like to do:

```
ls -ltr | tail -3
```

to confirm that the file I'm expecting is indeed there.

To avoid typing it too often, I add to my `~/.bach_profile`:

```
alias ltr="ls -ltr | tail -3"
```

`Bash`
[doesn't accept](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7131683/700648)
parameters, but we can write

```
ltr() {
    ls -ltr "${1}" | tail -3
}
```

After (say) something downloaded, this makes it possible to type `ltr ~/Downloads`.

But I can no longer type just `ltr`. I must now type `ltr .`.

How can I add a default parameter to a `Bash` function?

(I'm in the macOS Terminal, in case it makes a difference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default parameter value like this:

```sh
ltr() {
   ls -ltr "${1:-.}" | tail -3
}
```

It will use `.` as argument to `ls -ltr` if `$1` is missing.

With this you can use like this:

```sh
ltr ~/Documents
ltr ~/Downloads
ltr
```

[Please read this about parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Re: parsing the output of ls: IIUC, this applies only if I had inherited someone else's files or file system. In that case I'd need to guard against errors in the output, blundering commands, or downright trojans. But if I'm the one who added every file (with no unusual characters) aside from system files, then I'm considerably safer (with the exception of github-downloaded files etc). Is that about right?

Comment: @Sam Yes in that case you should be fine

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but in this case it might be better to use this:

```
ltr() {
    ls -ltr "$@" | tail -3
}
```

The `"$@"` expands to all of the arguments passed to `ltr`, so you can pass several arguments... or none at all, and whatever you pass gets passed on to `ls -ltr`.

Comment: I think I see where you're going. It might be handy to devise it such that the command mingles the output of two or more directories, and reverse-sorts by timestamp, then passes the output to tail.

Comment: @Sam Right. Or you can pass additional flags to `ls`, for example `ltr -ia /path/to/dir` would include invisible files and inode numbers while listing /path/to/dir.