# How Can I add a flag to alias?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to add a flag to alias, in my case I want do it for [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat). e.g.

```
mybat -a = 'bat --paging=always [file e.g .zshrc]'
mybat -n = 'bat --paging=never [file e.g .zshrc] '
```

I also wrote and tested the following code, but it did not work:

```
mybat() {
  local OPTIND value
  while getopts ":an" option; do
    case $option in
      a) value=never ;;
      n) value=always ;;
      ?) echo "invalid option: $OPTARG"; return 1 ;;
    esac
  done
  bat --paging=$value
}
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: I really get rid of nearly all alias and switch to functions, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter .

Comment: How did you run your function?

Comment: Ummm.
How did you run my function?
I run like this now:

`set -xv; mybat -a .zshrc; set +xv`

Output:

`set -xv; mybat -a .zshrc; set +xv`
`+/bin/zsh:8> mybat -a .zshrc`
`+mybat:1> local OPTIND value`
`+mybat:2> getopts :an option`
`+mybat:3> case a (a)`
`+mybat:4> value=never`
`+mybat:2> getopts :an option`
`+mybat:9> bat '--paging=never`

Normally, I run like this:
`mybat -a .zshrc`
But it does not work, it does not show me the contents of the file (`.zshrc` file in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have `bat` so I substituted `cat` and added a few `cat`-specific flags:

```
$ man cat
```

> ```
>    -A, --show-all
>           equivalent to -vET
>
>    -b, --number-nonblank
>           number nonempty output lines, overrides -n
>
>    -E, --show-ends
>           display $ at end of each line
>
>    -n, --number
>           number all output lines
> ```

One function approach where we simply replace the first short option with its corresponding long option:

```
mycat() {

unset value

inputs="$@"
option="${inputs%% *}"                    # assumes only looking to parse first input arg

case $option in
    -A) value='--show-all';        shift ;;
    -b) value='--number-nonblank'; shift ;;
    -E) value='--show-ends';       shift ;;
    -n) value='--number';          shift ;;
esac

set -xv
cat ${value} "$@"                         # don't wrap ${value} in double quotes otherwise mycat() call with no flags will be invoked as "cat '' <filename>" and generate an error
set +xv
}
```

**NOTE:** remove the `set -xv/+xv` once satisfied the function is working as planned

Test file:

```
$ cat words.dat
I am a man      post-tab           # <tab> between "man" and "post-tab"
I am not a man I
am a man
```

Taking the function for a test drive:

```
$ mycat -n words.dat
+ cat --number words.dat
 1  I am a man      post-tab
 2  I am not a man I
 3  am a man

$ mycat -A words.dat
+ cat --show-all words.dat
I am a man^Ipost-tab$                    # ^I == <tab>
I am not a man I$
am a man$

$ mycat -b words.dat
+ cat --number-nonblank words.dat
     1  I am a man      post-tab
     2  I am not a man I
     3  am a man

$ mycat -E words.dat
+ cat --show-ends words.dat
I am a man      post-tab$
I am not a man I$
am a man$

$ mycat -A -n words.dat                  # 2x options; only replace 1st option
+ cat --show-all -n words.dat
     1  I am a man^Ipost-tab$
     2  I am not a man I$
     3  am a man$

$ mycat words.dat                        # no options
+ cat words.dat
I am a man      post-tab
I am not a man I
am a man
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with the alias approach, define 2x different aliases, eg:

```
mybata='bat --paging=always'
mybatn='bat --paging=never'
```

**NOTE:** pick aliases that are short-to-type and easy-to-remmber, eg, `mybata` vs `mybat_a` vs `mybat-a` vs `mba` ...

Comment: Thanks and yes this way working fine, but I want use flag.