# Can you concatenate a Bash alias with a string without spaces?

Tags: bash, alias

I want to create an alias like this

```
alias kns='kubectl config set-context --current --namespace'
```

And add the required argument to --namespace (i.e. =default) on the command line. Is this possible?

I know I can create

```
alias kns='kubectl config set-context --current
```

And add both the flag and argument on the command line

```
kns --namespace=default
```

But I want to avoid typing --namespace every time. So my question is really:

- How do I concatenate an alias with some string without any spaces between?

Comment: Use a function. See: `help function`

Comment: This is what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7131683/8416360

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$1` is the first argument. `${1:-default}` uses the word `default`, if the first argument has been omitted or is empty.

```
kns ()
{
  kubectl config set-context --current --namespace="${1:-default}"
}
```