# Pass build argument to bash command in Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

Currently, my workflow is to use an alias for the jupyter lab command via `RUN echo 'alias...'` at the end of my Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo 'alias jupyterlab="jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8117 --no-browser --allow-root"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

which enables me to open up the JupyterLab container in my browser at port-number 8117, using just the command `jupyterlab`.

I would like to try to generalise this so that any valid `port_number` can be submitted as a build argument when building the Dockerfile, via e.g.,

```
docker build -t <image_name> . --build-arg PORTNUM=<port_number>
```

by changing the Dockerfile. Since Bash `alias` doesn't take arguments, I tried to adapt [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter):

```
RUN echo 'jupyterlab() { jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0 --port="$PORTNUM" --no-browser --allow-root ; }' >> ~/.bashrc
```

but now I get error

```
traitlets.traitlets.TraitError: The 'port' trait of a ServerApp instance must be an int, but a value of '' <class 'str'> was specified.
```

which suggests that no argument ended up being passed to the $PORTNUM. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I think you may need to take the quotes out from around `"$PORTNUM"`.  Maybe try referencing it like `--port=$PORTNUM` or `--port=${PORTNUM}`

Comment: Usually a container startup doesn't read shell dotfiles at all, so the `.bashrc` file has no effect; and it usually doesn't run a shell, so a bash-specific `alias` also has no effect.  Is this in the context of a larger container setup?  What's the main container `CMD`?