# Need the progress/status when using sleep

Tags: linux, bash

In Linux,

```
sleep 10
```

It just hangs there for 10 seconds, I want to see some progress/status when sleeping, doable?

I don't want to use a for-loop to sleep 1 separately.

Comment: It is not possible to simultaneously do nothing for 10 seconds and do something for 10 seconds. If you want to do something, then you have to write some extra code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did waiting animation in my projects: [sshto](https://github.com/vaniacer/sshto) and [kube-dialog](https://github.com/vaniacer/kube-dialog)

Color variables from [here](https://github.com/vaniacer/bash_color)

```
XY(){ printf "\e[$2;${1}H$3"; }

cursor () {
    case $1 in
         on) stty  echo; printf "$CON";;
        off) stty -echo; printf "$COF";;
    esac
}

   x=$[COLUMNS/2-3]
   y=$[  LINES/2-3]
sand=( ⠁  ⠂  ⠄  ' ' )
#  {   small digits    }
sd=(₀ ₁ ₂ ₃ ₄ ₅ ₆ ₇ ₈ ₉)
bs='⠴⠷⠦' # bottom sand pile
ts='⠖'    #  top  sand pile
WAIT(){
    clear; cursor off; i=0; start=$SECONDS
    XY $[x-1]  $y    $UND$BLD$RED'       '$DEF                     # _______
    XY $[x-1] $[y+1]         $RED'╲'$DIM$UND'     '$DEF$red'╱'$DEF # ╲_____╱
    XY  $x    $[y+2]         $BLU'(  '$BLD$WHT'•'$BLD$BLU')'$DEF   #  (  •)
    XY  $x    $[y+3]         $BLU' ╲'$YLW"$ts"$BLD$BLU'╱'$DEF      #   ╲⠖╱
    XY  $x    $[y+4]         $BLU" ╱$YLW${sand[$i]}$BLD$BLU╲"$DEF  #   ╱⠂╲
    XY  $x    $[y+5]         $BLU'('$YLW"$bs"$BLD$BLU')'$DEF       #  (⠴⠷⠦)
    XY $[x-1] $[y+6]         $RED'╱'$RED'‾‾‾‾‾'$BLD$RED'╲'$DEF     # ╱‾‾‾‾‾╲
    XY $[x-1] $[y+7]     $DIM$RED'‾‾‾‾‾‾‾'$DEF                     # ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
    ( while true; do sleep 0.07
        printf -v counter "%03d" $[SECONDS-start]
        small="${sd[${counter:0:1}]}${sd[${counter:1:1}]}${sd[${counter:2:1}]}"
        XY $[x-1] $[y+1] $RED'╲'$DIM$UND" $small "$DEF$red'╱'$DEF
        XY  $x    $[y+4] $BLU" ╱$YLW${sand[$i]}$BLD$BLU╲"$DEF
        ((i++)); (($i==${#sand[@]})) && i=0;
    done ) & waiter=$!
}
```

Use it like this:

```
WAIT; sleep 10; GO
```

Animation looks like this:

[image]

Another good example of waiting animation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter/60058354#60058354)

Comment: OMG that looks really cool! I'll try this later today.